# Algorithms and Data Structures

Tags: algorithms, data-structure

I just started Masters on a different school than my bachelor degree and since Advanced algorithms is a compulsory subject and I never had Algo. for beginners, Im taking a bachelers level algorithms class, but it is in german. (I study my masters degree in english), therefore they just gave a book to read, some exercises to solve and then I can take the exam. Most of the exercises are about different algorithms and thats fine, but the first one is this [image]

Can anyone give me a hint how I can go about solving this? The book they gave me to read doesnt help at all.

Comment: As a warm-up problem, can you tell if the function $g(n) = n^2 \log_2(n^n)$ is $O(n^3 \log_2(n))$?

Comment: Possibly these identities will be helpful: $\log_p {n^f} = f\cdot \log_p n = f\frac{\log_q n}{\log_q p}$